# Broken pipe (Errno 32) when connecting to Neo4j from spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'am newone on spark.There is a issue when I run a job,but spark task was interrupted.I use spark on yarn,by 'yarn-client'.How could I config my spark job.
I submit the spark task client with 32g memory, submit the task to the yarn cluster, the cluster has 72 logical CPUs and 54g memory, and the database using neo4j,This is my source code:

```
build_graphdb_nodes = PythonOperator(
        task_id='fn_{0}_build_nodes_graphdb'.format(graph_spec.name),
        dag=dag,
        python_callable=neo4j_writer.write_neo4j_nodes,
        op_kwargs={
            'graph_specification': graph_spec.to_dict(),
            'spark_config': (
                SparkConfFactory()
                .set_master('yarn-client')
                .set_app_name('fn_{0}_build_nodes_graphdb'
                              .format(graph_spec.name))
                .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1000)
                .set("spark.executorEnv.HOME",
                     os.path.join('/tmp', str(uuid4())))
                .set("spark.scheduler.revive.interval", 3)
                .set("spark.task.maxFailures", 4)
                .set("spark.executor.instances", 1)
                .set("spark.executor.cores", 3)
                .set("spark.executor.memory", "5g" if DEBUG else "8g")
                .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "2g" if DEBUG else "4g")
            )
        },
        priority_weight=2
    )







20/06/26 00:45:56 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 17.1 in stage 37.0 (TID 3857, paidfnd105u.uatinfra-agd.gov.sg, partition 17,NODE_LOCAL, 4000 bytes)
20/06/26 01:00:59 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 17.1 in stage 37.0 (TID 3857, paidfnd105u.uatinfra-agd.gov.sg): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 317, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 759, in func
    r = f(it)
  File "/airflow/dags/fncore/tasks/neo4j_writer.py", line 310, in <lambda>
  File "/airflow/dags/fncore/tasks/neo4j_writer.py", line 219, in push_nodes
    commit_graphdb(neo_ctx, statements, maxretry)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/airflow/dags/fncore/utils/neo4j_conf.py", line 37, in get_neo4j_context
    neo4j_context.close()
  File "/tmp/pip-install-x42go6/neo4j-driver/neo4j/v1/api.py", line 259, in close
    self._disconnect(sync=True)
  File "/tmp/pip-install-x42go6/neo4j-driver/neo4j/v1/api.py", line 241, in _disconnect
    self._connection.sync()
  File "/tmp/pip-install-x42go6/neo4j-driver/neo4j/bolt/connection.py", line 324, in sync
    self.send()
  File "/tmp/pip-install-x42go6/neo4j-driver/neo4j/bolt/connection.py", line 241, in send
    self.socket.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 744, in sendall
    v = self.send(data[count:])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 710, in send
    v = self._sslobj.write(data)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

20/06/26 01:00:59 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 17.2 in stage 37.0 (TID 3858, paidfnd105u.uatinfra-agd.gov.sg, partition 17,NODE_LOCAL, 4000 bytes)
20/06/26 01:16:01 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 17.2 in stage 37.0 (TID 3858, paidfnd105u.uatinfra-agd.gov.sg): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 317, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 759, in func
    r = f(it)
  File "/airflow/dags/fncore/tasks/neo4j_writer.py", line 310, in <lambda>
  File "/airflow/dags/fncore/tasks/neo4j_writer.py", line 219, in push_nodes
    commit_graphdb(neo_ctx, statements, maxretry)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/airflow/dags/fncore/utils/neo4j_conf.py", line 37, in get_neo4j_context
    neo4j_context.close()
  File "/tmp/pip-install-x42go6/neo4j-driver/neo4j/v1/api.py", line 259, in close
    self._disconnect(sync=True)
  File "/tmp/pip-install-x42go6/neo4j-driver/neo4j/v1/api.py", line 241, in _disconnect
    self._connection.sync()
  File "/tmp/pip-install-x42go6/neo4j-driver/neo4j/bolt/connection.py", line 324, in sync
    self.send()
  File "/tmp/pip-install-x42go6/neo4j-driver/neo4j/bolt/connection.py", line 241, in send
    self.socket.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 744, in sendall
    v = self.send(data[count:])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 710, in send
    v = self._sslobj.write(data)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

These type of errors are usually due to network issue.

You can see in the stack trace, its from the connection to Neo4J:

```
/tmp/pip-install-x42go6/neo4j-driver/neo4j/bolt/connection.py
```

You can refer [this post](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/broken-pipe-error-while-running-a-spark-job-from-namenode/td-p/197243) for more details.

Another cause is [using big files](https://sharing.luminis.eu/blog/neo4j-for-python-users-and-broken-pipe-error/):

> when you try to write huge files (more than 4000 nodes + 4000 relations), the performance of the communication between Python and Neo4j degrades. You probably get the Broken Pipe error which does not let you upload more nodes and relations into your Neo4j database.

Comment: Thanks.How can I fix this problem. Linux platforms impose an upper limit on the number of concurrent files a user may have open.ulimit -n and my server is :4096 ,Is this a big influence?